# Texture paint material shader not showing on Cycles render. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting, shader-nodes

Texture paint material shader not showing on Cycles render. Material shows clearly only on Eevee and on Cycles Viewport preview it displays as a blob-like mess.

Any thoughts?

[image: Eevee preview]

[image: Cycles viewport Preview]

[image: Cycles rendered result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a duplicate of the object turned off for the viewer but not for the render.